# Login prompt reports 4 failed login but the log shows only 1 entry

Tags: ssh, security, redhat

I just logged into my small homeserver and I saw this message:

```
Last failed login: Sun Jan 14 17:08:42 CET 2024 from 192.168.1.111 on ssh:notty
There were 4 failed login attempts since the last successful login.
```

I switched to the root user and I ran

```
root@homeserver ~]# egrep "Failed|Failure" /var/log/secure
Jan 14 17:08:42 homeserver sshd[4906]: Failed password for invalid user podman from 192.168.1.111 port 59183 ssh2
```

Why the first prompt is reporting 4 failed logins whereas the egrep command returns only 1 entry from the `secure` log? Do I have to grep on something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your lines of logs after successful login and the fact that you have inspected `/var/log/secure`, I assume that you are running Redhat/CentOS on your machine. Actually, the first prompt you mentioned in your question may probably be the output of `pam_lastlog`, whose manual page reads:

```
PAM_LASTLOG(8)

... (omitted for brevity)

OPTIONS

       ... (omitted for brevity)

       showfailed
           Display number of failed login attempts and the date of the last failed attempt from btmp. The date is not displayed when nodate is specified.

       ... (omitted for brevity)
```

Note that the manpage states clearly the number is retrived from `btmp`, that is, `/var/log/btmp`, another log file to record unsuccessful logins. Unfortunately, it is a binary file and you cannot inspect it using `cat` and `grep` commands. As a way round, you can use `last -f /var/log/btmp` command to check what the file records, according to [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/325495).

By the way, it might be helpful if you check the manpage of `pam_lastlog` and [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/127211/why-are-utmp-wtmp-and-btmp-called-as-they-are) for further reading.

Comment: Indeed it's about RHEL 9.
And yes, the number of entries from `last -f /var/log/btmp` matches the number of failed logins. Thank you for your explanation!